# Third column cell should be product of two numbers in first and second column in excel

Tags: excel-formula

In excel sheet I want to multiply first column cells with corresponding second column cells and auto fill the corresponding third column cell.

Example:
When I enter values as the following

A1 cell 2 , B1 cell 5 then c1 cell should autofill without selecting the cell with their product value
A2 cell 5 , B2 cell 5 then c2 cell should autofill without selecting the cell with their product value
Similarly with all rows which have column 1 and column 2 filled.

How can I solve this excel sheet auto filling problem?

Comment: Have you tried to use excel tables? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-calculated-columns-in-an-excel-table-873fbac6-7110-4300-8f6f-aafa2ea11ce8

Answer (score 1):

in C1 .. put `=A1*B1` then drag the cell downwards..

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can select all the cells in column C where you want that formula, enter =A1*B1 and then do CTRL+Enter...

This puts the formula in each cell without dragging any formatting...